# Dependency injection how to avoid hiding dependencies to stateful objects like a validator

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I would like to have your opinion about such a situation, the code is quite simple
to should be easy to follow:

```
@Component
class MyService {
    
    AusiliaryService ausService;

    public MyService(AusiliaryService ausService) {
        ...
    }

    public boolean isAccountValid(Account account) {

     AccountValidator accountValidator = new AccountValidator(account);
     boolean isValid = accountValidator.isValid(account);
     if(isValid) {
        ausService.openAccount(account);
     }
    }
}
```

**Note** that `AusiliaryService` is also spring managed and we are using constructor injection.

In this class `AccountValidator` is a **dependency** of `MyService` but it does not appear in the constructor so we could say the **visibility** of this dependency is somehow **hidden**.

Since we are hardcoding the instantiation of
`AccountValidator accountValidator = new AccountValidator(account);`

We may also have some potential issues with writing unit tests `MyService`, unless you may think such any unit tests should also impact `AccountValidator`, which for me would be a valid line of thought.

A possible work around for both "issues" would be to use a factory, to remove from  MyService the responsability to instantiate
`AccountValidator` object.

```
@Component
class MyService {
    
    AusiliaryService ausService;
    AccountValidatorFactory accountValidatorFactory;

    public MyService(AusiliaryService ausService, AccountValidatorFactory accountValidatorFactory;) {
        ...
    }

    public boolean isAccountValid(Account account) {

     AccountValidator accountValidator = accountValidatorFactory.getValidator(account);
     boolean isValid = accountValidator.isValid(account);
     if(isValid) {
        ausService.openAccount(account);
     }
    }
}
```

Note that also `AccountValidatorFactory` is spring managed and we are using constructor injection.

A cons of this solution could be though the proliferation of such factories classes, if you use this kind of pattern often in your code.

What would is your approach in such situations ?
Which kind of solution would you prefer ?
Would be possible to make `AccountValidator` also spring managed to help with this, how would that be done ?

Comment: I would prefer a third option, which to [prevent the use of factories](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/abstract-factories/), inject the validator through the constructor, and pass the runtime data object `Account` to the validator solely through the `isValid` method, thus preventing the [code smell of injecting runtime data in components during construction](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can just make `AccountValidator` a managed spring bean. You can accomplish this the same way that you made this class (MyService), or how you would have made the factory classes you describe, managed - by adding @Component.

If you need to preserve the semantics, e.g. if this bean is not thread safe and you need to create new ones every time, you can make it a protype bean.

Here is an example, and you can see that it is being injected in a way that is using spring libraries without your own factories. it will print:

```
Example.MyValidator(id=0)
Example.MyValidator(id=1)
Example.MyValidator(id=2)
```

here is the code:

```java
package org.example;

import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;
    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner() {
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println(myService.state());
            }
            context.close();
        };
    }

    @Service
    static class MyService {
        private final ObjectProvider<MyValidator> myValidators;

        MyService(ObjectProvider<MyValidator> myValidators) {
            this.myValidators = myValidators;
        }

        String state() {
            return myValidators.getObject().toString();
        }
    }

    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Component
    @ToString
    static class MyValidator {
        private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        private final int id;

        MyValidator() {
            this.id = counter.getAndIncrement();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so ObjectProvider<MyValidator> would act as a factory and be constructor injected right ?

Comment: yes............